# Check if in input not url address Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 inputs with social accounts, I need get login this social accounts. I need deny write links in this inputs. How I can do it?

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'google_plus' => 'required|not:url',
        'twitter' => 'required|not:url',
    ]);
```

`not:url` not working..

Example: I need deny link: https://twitter.com/loginUser And allow only: `loginUser`

Comment: Consider using the `regex` flag..

Comment: Either use a regex, or create a custom validator https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: You could also go easier on your users, and accept URLs and parse out the handle or whatever it is you really want.

Comment: @tremby raises a very good point. Why not make things easier on your user? You know that `twitter.com/loginUser` can be changed to `loginUser` - do it for them automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, follow the instructions in
[laravel validation, custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules)
to create a new rule called NotUrl like this:

```
class NotUrl implements Rule
{   
   public function passes($attribute, $value)
   {
      return !filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
   }

   public function message()
   {
      return 'The :attribute must not be a complete URL.';
   }
}
```

Then validate like this:

```
use App\Rules\NotUrl;

    $this->validate($request, [
            'google_plus' => ['required', new NotUrl],
            'twitter' => ['required', new NotUrl],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `regex` validator or create a [custom validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules) that implements the rule you're after.

For example, something like `regex:^https://twitter.com/.+` would validate an input that starts with that domain.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of validators is to stop submission if it doesn't meet the requirements. Based on what you described, you don't want to stop submission, but just trim it.

In this case, don't put any rule on that field. When saving it to the database, use preg_replace:

```
$pattern = "/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";

$newValue = preg_replace($pattern, "", $request->twitter);
```